# Blinking Caret Not Showing up in Input Text Field

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want one of my input text boxes to be the stage focus as well as have the blinking caret without the user needing to click inside the text field. I've been searching around frantically for an answer to this question, and everyone's answer boils down to this code: (the instance name of the text field being "input")

```
stage.focus = input;
input.setSelection(0, input.text.length);
```

But for some reason this code isn't working for me. Anyone have any idea why?

*Update*

For some reason this works:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,update);
function update(e:MouseEvent){
    stage.focus = input;
}
```

And this does as well but the caret doesn't blink:

```
var counter:int=0;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
function update(e:Event){
    counter++;
    if(counter>30){
        stage.focus = input;
    }
}
```

This still doesn't satisfy my question though, why do you need a mouse click of some type in order to make my desired action work properly?

Comment: Silly question, but are you absolutely *certain* that the `TextField` is set to be `input`?

Comment: Yes @Marcela, the textfield is of type input. That's a good question though, usually it's small details like that that cause the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.. How about if you set focus to happen inside a mouseClick function?

2.. Try this

```
    stage.focus = input;
    input.text = " "; //with a space (for blank but not empty);
    input.setSelection(0, input.text.length);
```

3.. Bail out scenario then this utility might help or at least you'll learn something from its code [Link here](http://greencollective.nl/blog/?p=16)

Comment: Yeah, that's the conclusion I came to above. I guess I'll have to deal with it. Thanks for the link as well.

Comment: I don't understand why this doesn't work properly with my second method though...

Comment: `input.stage.focus = input;` may work without a mouseclick. I'm not on Flash right now to test unfortunately. It might require the click in order to differentiate between active/non active fields rather than all textfields on screen having a blinking cursor by default